# Loop an ArrayList with ONE method

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

can someone help me how to shorten this code by using only ONE loop through the list which both deleteFromList() and increaseAge() can use??

```
private void deleteFromList() {
    System.out.println("Type the name of the person you want to delete: ");
    String nameOfPerson = keyboard.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < allPersons.size(); i++) {
        if (allPersons.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfPerson)) {
            allPersons.remove(i);
            System.out.println("The person has been deleted!");
        }
    }
}


private void increaseAge() {
    System.out.println("Type in the persons name: ");
    String nameOfPerson = keyboard.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < allPersons.size(); i++) {
        if (allPersons.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfPerson)) {
            Person person = allPersons.get(i);
            person.setAge();
            System.out.println("Persons age have been changed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the name entered is the same for both deletion and incrementing the age?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think the question is simply how to reduce code duplication.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to avoid the duplicate iteration and comparison logic between the two methods. The good news is, if you're using Java 8 you don't have to loop at all:

```
private void deleteFromList() {
    System.out.println("Type the name of the person you want to delete: ");
    String nameOfPerson = keyboard.nextLine();
    allPersons.removeIf(p -> p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfPerson));
}

private void increaseAge() {
    System.out.println("Type in the persons name: ");
    String nameOfPerson = keyboard.nextLine();
    allPersons.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfPerson))
            .forEach(Person::setAge);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following could help? Names should probably be optimized ;-)
Using a general method `handlePerson` so that you can put in specific consumers, if you need them.

```
public void handlePerson(String personName, Consumer<Person> personConsumer) {
    allPersons.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(personName))
        .forEach(personConsumer);
}


public void increaseAge() {
    System.out.println("Type in the persons name: ");
    handlePerson(keyboard.nextLine(), Person::setAge));
    // or if you really want to do it all in the consumer:
    handlePerson(keyboard.nextLine(), p -> { 
        p.setAge(); 
        System.out.println("Persons age have been changed");
    });
}

public void deletePerson() {
    System.out.println("Type in the persons name: ");
    String personName = keyboard.nextLine();
    // of course no way to handle deletion via consumer ;-)
    if (allPersons.removeIf(p -> p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(personName))) {
        System.out.println("The person has been deleted!");
    }

}
```

You may also want to introduce a separate `Predicate` if you are using `p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(personName)` more often.